# Akka: currentEventsByPersistenceId always returns zero for 'eventEnvelope.timestamp'

Tags: akka, cqrs, event-sourcing, lagom, akka-persistence

I am experimenting with the `currentEventsByPersistenceId` query from `akka-persistence-query` to retrieve and process events stored in the messages table. However, I've encountered an issue where the `EventEnvelope` returned by this query has a timestamp field value of 0, instead of the insertion milliseconds since the epoch of 1970-01-01. Interestingly, the proper timestamp is available in the messages table, and I can retrieve it successfully if I switch to using the `currentEventsByTag` query instead of `currentEventsByPersistenceId`.

Here is the sample piece of code I tried

1. `eventEnvelope.timestamp` always returns 0 in the following code.

```
val allEvents: Source[Any, NotUsed] = readJournal.currentPersistenceIds.flatMapConcat {
        persistenceId =>
          readJournal
            .currentEventsByPersistenceId(persistenceId, 1, Long.MaxValue)
            .map { eventEnvelope =>
              logger.info(s"timestamp = ${eventEnvelope.timestamp}, PID = ${eventEnvelope.persistenceId}, SEQ = ${eventEnvelope.sequenceNr}")
              // timestamp always returning zero. persistenceId and sequenceNr is printed correctly as in messages table
              eventEnvelope.event
            }
      }
```

2. `eventEnvelope.timestamp` is printed correctly as per the messages table in the following code.

```
val tag = "specific-tag"
val allEventsByTag: Source[Any, NotUsed] = readJournal
        .currentEventsByTag(tag, NoOffset)
        .map { eventEnvelope =>
          logger.info(s"timestamp = ${eventEnvelope.timestamp}, PID = ${eventEnvelope.persistenceId}, SEQ = ${eventEnvelope.sequenceNr}")
          // timestamp is printed correctly as per the messages table
          eventEnvelope.event
        }
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Comment: Note that the implementation of `currentEventsByPersistenceId` is provided by the plugin.  Which persistence plugin are you using?  Since this is apparently Lagom, that boils down to "Cassandra or JDBC"?

Comment: Yes, I am using akka.persistence Cassandra

Comment: I could see that `CassandraReadJournal` implementation of `currentEventsByPeristenceId` uses constructor of `EventEnvelop` where timestamp is always set to zero, where in for `currentEventsByTag`, timestamp is set from offset (a timeUUID). Is there an alternate method to be used?